# Unmet Peer Dependency causes

Tags: node.js, angular, terminal, npm

Been trying to set up my Angular2 app in Webstorm, and came across a problem with npm install, where it fails because 'reflect-metadata@0.1.8' has an unmet peer dependency. I've tried to install it manually with

```
      sudo npm install reflect-metadata@0.1.8
```

but it doesn't work. This is the terminal output when trying to npm install:

```
      sudo npm install 
      angular2-starter@1.0.0 /home/chase/angular2-starter
      ├── es6-promise@3.2.1  extraneous
      └── UNMET PEER DEPENDENCY reflect-metadata@0.1.8

      npm WARN optional Skipping failed optional dependency /chokidar/fsevents:
      npm WARN notsup Not compatible with your operating system or  architecture: fsevents@1.0.14
      npm WARN angular2@2.0.0-beta.17 requires a peer of reflect-metadata@0.1.2 but none was installed.
      npm WARN angular2-starter@1.0.0 No description
      npm WARN angular2-starter@1.0.0 No repository field.
```

This is my Package.json file:

```
    {
      "name": "angular2-starter",
      "version": "1.0.0",
      "scripts": {
      "start": "concurrently \"npm run tsc:w\" \"npm run lite\" ",
      "lite": "lite-server",
      "postinstall": "typings install",
      "tsc": "tsc",
      "tsc:w": "tsc -w",
      "typings": "typings"
   },
      "license": "ISC",
      "dependencies": {
      "@angular/common": "2.0.0-rc.5",
      "@angular/compiler": "2.0.0-rc.5",
      "@angular/core": "2.0.0-rc.5",
      "@angular/forms": "0.3.0",
      "@angular/http": "2.0.0-rc.5",
      "@angular/platform-browser": "2.0.0-rc.5",
      "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "2.0.0-rc.5",
      "@angular/router": "3.0.0-rc.1",
      "@angular/router-deprecated": "2.0.0-rc.2",
      "@angular/upgrade": "2.0.0-rc.5",
      "angular2": "^2.0.0-beta.17",
      "angular2-in-memory-web-api": "0.0.15",
      "bootstrap": "^3.3.6",
      "core-js": "^2.4.0",
      "es6-shim": "^0.35.1",
      "reflect-metadata": "^0.1.2",
      "rxjs": "^5.0.0-beta.6",
      "systemjs": "0.19.27",
      "zone.js": "^0.6.15"
       },
      "devDependencies": {
      "concurrently": "^2.0.0",
      "lite-server": "^2.2.0",
      "typescript": "^1.8.10",
      "typings": "^1.0.4"
     } 
     }
```

Any Ideas? Thanks

Answer (score 2):

The `npm WARN angular2@2.0.0-beta.17 requires a peer of reflect-metadata@0.1.2 but none was installed.` indicates that you need the proper version and you do not have it installed.  You can change this by correcting the package.json to not have the caret (^) before the version.

```
  "reflect-metadata": "0.1.2",
  "rxjs": "5.0.0-beta.6",
```

Removing the caret will install the specific version. This will however prevent updated versions of being installed.

Comment: yeah, basically you've installed the dependency but is a newer one than the specified. so yes, removing the caret (^) will install the specific version and you won't get any warning.

Comment: Correct, and this should solve the current problem of a library being updated to be newer than what the module requiring it is expecting.  At some point, the original install (angular) should get updated to use the newer version, and the caret (^) can be returned.